# Issue with changeHandler, component re renders every time i do some change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, onchange

My plan is to make stepper component in modal so the every step will have own component.So i use switch case logic and that works fine for me it return the step and step component properly. I have issue on change handler, when i start to type it seems that my component re renders every time i do some change. Here is a parent Modal component

```
export function ContactModal(props) {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(0)
    let stepArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


    const handleNextStep = () => {
        const nextStep = step + 1;
        if (step === 1) {
            let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
            if (!checked) {
                alert("You must check at least one checkbox.")
            } else {
                setStep(nextStep)
            }
        } else {
            setStep(nextStep)
        }
    }
    const handleBackStep = () => {
        const back = step - 1;
        setStep(back)
    }
    const inputHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.setData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        }));
    };

    const checkboxHandler = (event) => {

        let savedData;
        savedData = {
            ...props.data,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
        };
        props.setData(savedData)

    };

    const handleChangeTimepicker = (newValue, name) => {
        props.setData({...props.data, [name]: new Date(newValue)});
    };

    let CurrentStep;

    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            CurrentStep = () => (
                <RequestProject nextStep={handleNextStep} onHide={props.onHide} step={step} setStep={setStep} />
            );
            break;
        case 1:
            CurrentStep = () => (
                <Step1 checkboxHandler={checkboxHandler} nextStep={handleNextStep} data={props.data} />
            );
            break;
        case 2:
            CurrentStep = () => (
                <Step2 handleChangeTimepicker={handleChangeTimepicker} data={props.data} nextStep={handleNextStep} />
            );
            break;
        case 3:
            CurrentStep = () => (
                <Step3 checkboxHandler={checkboxHandler} nextStep={handleNextStep} data={props.data} />
            );
            break;
        case 4:
            CurrentStep = () => (
                <Step4 inputHandler={inputHandler} nextStep={handleNextStep} data={props.data} setData={props.setData} />
            );
            break;
        default:
            CurrentStep = null;
    }


    return (
        <Modal {...props} size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
            {step > 0 && (
                <Modal.Header className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bt-none w-100  px-5">
                    <p onClick={handleBackStep} className="text-md m-0 cursor-pointer text-primary">
                        <IoIosArrowBack />Back
                    </p>
                    <StepperDots stepArray={stepArray} step={step} />
                    <p onClick={props.onHide} className="text-md m-0 cursor-pointer text-primary">
                        Close
                    </p>
                </Modal.Header>
            )}
            <Modal.Body>
                {CurrentStep && <CurrentStep />}
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>

    )
}
```

and here is my child compoenet :

```
export function Step4({nextStep, data, setData}) {

    const changeHandler = useCallback((event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    }, [setData]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
                <h4 className="mb-3 w-50 text-center">About your company</h4>
                <Form className="my-5">
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label>Your Name <span className="text-gray">(optional)</span></Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control onChange={changeHandler} type="text" value={data.name} name="name"/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label>Your Company Name <span className="text-gray">(optional)</span></Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control onChange={changeHandler} type="text" value={data.companyName} name="companyName"/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label>Your Website/Instagram </Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control onChange={changeHandler} type="text" value={data.website} name="website"/>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>

                <button onClick={nextStep} className="btn text-white mt-5">Next</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

i try also to set my state upper level and pass that as prop, but still same issue.

Comment: That's how react works, every time you set state it triggers a re-render. What is the problem that this re-render causes?

Comment: Do you have problem with losing input's focus on re-render?

Comment: Yes, i can put only one letter at the time. I think what is happening is that every time i put letter or do any change on input it cause re render whole component and cant write the text inside input

Comment: Try adding a "key" to "CurrentStep" component.

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

Answer (score 0):

You are having some problems related to bubbling:

```
// This component is receiving "data" as props, then every time "data" changes the component will be rerendered

export function Step4({nextStep, data, setData})
```

Then, in the parent component:

```
// "setData" and "data" passed to component "Step4" are received from the parent component (I mean, the parent of this "parent" component), then any time "props.data" changes, this component will change as well as its childrens
case 4:
  CurrentStep = () => (
    <Step4 
      inputHandler={inputHandler} 
      nextStep={handleNextStep} 
      data={props.data} 
      setData={props.setData} 
    />
  );
break;
```

So in summary, try to create a context or to store the data in the component you need to consume it. There are also other strategies like memoize.